# ASP.NET Authenticate Using [Authorize]

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I defined a Controller to force authentication by using the [Authorize] attribute. When a session times out, the request is still passed down and executed instead of forcing a redirect.

I do use FormsAuthentication to login and logoff users.

Any ideas on how to control that?

Example:

```
[Authorize]
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to ask this question separately, but as we're here, does ASP.NET MVC have inbuilt authentication shizzle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a quick and dirty test, this worked fine for me. Can you post your Web.Config file?

Comment: my web.config is standard out of the box with the simple addition of: 

  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"/>
  </authentication>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, ASP.NET MVC builds on top of traditional ASP.NET. Yes, there is an "built authentication shizzle"... it's the *exact* same Membership API that traditional ASP.NET uses.

Meaning... something else is the problem here. Maybe you have sliding sessions turned on... or maybe the timeout is higher than you thought, etc.

Comment: i had to turn off sliding sessions and it seems to of resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

To track user sessions ASP.NET uses the *ASP.NET_SessionId* cookie. To track authenticated users ASP.NET uses the *ASPXAUTH* cookie (by default).

When a session times out the *ASP.NET_SessionId* cookie might no longer be sent by the client but the *ASPXAUTH* cookie is still sent which might explain why your action is rendered.

To override default forms authentication values you might take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx). I also suggest you to use the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension to see exactly which cookies are sent by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329123/forms-in-masterpage-and-views), I would guess you are not getting to this controller at all.

Comment: i get into the controller but i am stuck within the Index method so i can't use the same controller for other methods because they all post back to the Index method. Example: a path like /projects/edit/1 would post the form to ProjectController method Index()

Comment: Sounds like you have either a form within a form on your page, or a bad routing setup.  Can you post your routes and the view source from the page in question?